# Responsive design - Iphone portrait vs landscape

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

If Iphone 5 (320x568) is in the portrait mode its width is 320px. When it is in the landscape mode is its width 320px and orientation is landscape, or its width is 568px and the orientation is landscape. I am talking about the width that CSS sees.

In other words, does this code work in landscape mode as well, so the site (wrapped by #container) occupies the whole screen in this case and not just the 320px?

```
@media (max-width: 568px) and (min-width:320) {
#container {
    max-width: 790px;
    width: 100%;
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want this

Portrait is taller, landscape is wider.

```
@media all and (orientation:portrait) {
  /* Styles for Portrait screen */
}
@media all and (orientation:landscape) {
  /* Styles for Landscape screen */
}
```

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-orientation-styles/

Short answer: For an iphone 5 with those dimensions, your code will always apply.

Explanation: Think of `min-width` as

> The minimum width on which this CSS will apply (anything lower will not count)

likewise consider `max-width` as

> The maximum width on which this CSS will apply (anything higher will not count)

Note that you are applying a `width:100%` in a range between `320px` and `568px`. This means that the line `max-width: 790px;` will never be executed since the highest value `width:100%` can return is `568px`

Comment: I understand this. I do not know if in this particular example the landscape width is 568 or 320?

Comment: In this particular example: While in portrait: `width:320px` and for landscape: `width:568px`. I will edit my answer to address your question

Comment: Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes, it does answer it.